# How do I get the plane?

Tags: the-gold-factory

How do I add iron bars through source code to get the plane? Do I need iron bars? I have tried to wait but it is taking forever.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply modify the value of `ironbar` global variable to a number:

```
window.ironbar = 200
// or simply
ironbar = 200
```

Comment: How would I do that I tried typing it into the basic.js but it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

To get extra iron bars (or anything) in The Gold Factory, you would need to edit the save game code. Do this by changing the decoding the base 64 save game code. You can use this website. https://www.base64encode.org/ The second number after the decryption should be the number of iron bars you have, while the first number is the amount of gold bars you have. Change that, then encrypt the code again. Add "encrypted" to the end of the code, and there you go! Here's my code:

MTAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDB8MTAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDB8MTZ8MTYwfDMzfDYwfDEzNHwwfDJ8MXw1OTB8MXwxfDF8Mjd8MXwwfDB8MHwwfDB8MHwwfDB8MHwwfDB8MHwwfDB8MHwwfDN8MHwxfDN8NHw0fDF8MnxZb3V8VGhpcyBpcyB5b3UufDB8MHwwfDB8ZmFsc2V8ZmFsc2V8ZmFsc2V8MHxmYWxzZXx0cnVlfHRodW5kZXJ8NXwzfDF8MTd8ZmFsc2V8MHw5OTk5OTk5OTl8OTk5OTk5OTk5fDB8RGlhbW9uZCBTd29yZHx0cnVlfHRydWV8dHJ1ZXx0cnVlfHRydWV8dHJ1ZXxmYWxzZXxmYWxzZXxmYWxzZXxmYWxzZXxmYWxzZXx0cnVlfDV8ZmFsc2V8dHJ1ZQencrypted

Answer (score -1):

Press F12 to open up the javascript console.  the type "ironbar=5000000"